# Want to Map with value and keyword in json body

Tags: json, postman

I want to retrieve data which is in json body to test results.
Want to map with correct value
Ex:  "medInfo": "(Numeric) Please enter numeric value: 22.0"
I want to get that "medInfo" has value and value is "(Numeric) Please enter numeric value: 22.0"

Tried with following code. But it just check values are available only.
var expected = "(Numeric) Please enter numeric value: 22.0"
tests["MedInfo contains" + expected] = responseBody.has(expected);

This is the json body in response

```
[
{
    "requestId": "131024",
    "investigations": [
        {
            "investigationId": null,
            "specimenName": "",
            "specimenDescription": "",
            "specimenLocation": "",
            "investigationName": "INVN01",
            "investigationDescription": "Investigate N01",
            "analysisName": "",
            "analysisDescription": "",
            "profileName": "",
            "medInfo": "(Numeric) Please enter numeric value: 22.0"
        }
    ],
```

Here is the test I have tried

```
var expected = "(Numeric) Please enter numeric value: 22.0"
tests["MedInfo contains" + expected] = responseBody.has(expected);
```

Here is the response received

PASS MedInfo contains(Numeric) Please enter numeric value: 22.0

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var mediaInfo = jsonData[0].investigations[0].medInfo
```

`jsonData[0]` Assuming that we are getting 0 index value.
investigations[0 Assuming that we are getting 0 index value.

You will get `mediaInfo` value from JSON.